# Harmonic vs circular regression

Tags: regression, circular-statistics

Is there a difference between harmonic and circular regression? I've been working with more longitudinal data recently and trying to model circadian patterns that involve transforming the time variable to sine and cosine terms. I've tried searching the google machine and cross validated to no avail.

Comment: Would you please post (or link to) data with at least a few cycles in it? Also, what is your preferred statistical software package or programming language?

Comment: It's soil surface temperature recorded every 1 hour between sites and a treatment. R is my preferred language. I was just wondering generally if there is a difference between harmonic and circular regression. They both seem similar in literature and websites I've found, but harmonic regression seems to be a component of spectral analysis. So just trying to get some clarification of the two terms/analyses.